# Remoting in c# and linq to sql?

Tags: c#, linq, remoting

I have a problem when running my application in virtual machine. It noticed

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
>
> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

My application uses remoting in C# and linq to sql to connect to get data, I have 1 server and 1 client, server runs then client can connect to server, when i run client form in the virtual machine, the data is loaded, but when I insert/update/delete data, that error appear.

Comment: Well, first you should catch your exceptions :). Second, you will likely need to change your authentication schema in SQL server, which is probably a question for SuperUser.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you try to run it under `debug` environment? this will help you to pin point the location of the exception, and probably understand the issue better.